# Android fragment won't load data until second time the tab is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, parse-platform, mpandroidchart

I am developing an Android app to track coffee consumption and I have 5 tabs as seen in the attached images. In one of the tabs(fragment), I have a viewPager that is used to display data in pie charts. I am having a strange issue where the data only is display when I click on the fragment the second time. Initially, it looks like this [Pie chart on the first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YufrI.png). When I click on the second time, it adds the information. [Piechart on the second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWe5.png). The package used to display data is https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.

I am not sure exactly where this is going wrong but I have attached the code for the TrackingFragment and some of the CostFragment(fragment inside fragment). The data is fetched from parse server client but I am fairly certain that the problem is with the initialization of the fragments.

Appreciate any help.

## TrackingFragment

```
public class TrackingFragment extends Fragment {

private static ArrayList<String> drinkNames;
private static String TAG = "TrackingFragment";
CaffeineFragment caffeineFragment;
CostFragment costFragment;
QuantityFragment quantityFragment;

public TrackingFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    costFragment = new CostFragment();
    caffeineFragment = new CaffeineFragment();
    quantityFragment = new QuantityFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tracking, container, false);

    ViewPager pager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    initViewPager(pager);

    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    return view;
}

private void initViewPager(ViewPager pager) {

    FragmentAdapter adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(costFragment, "Price");
    adapter.addFragment(caffeineFragment, "Caffeine");
    adapter.addFragment(quantityFragment, "Quantity");
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


static class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return fragmentList.size();
    }


    public void addFragment(Fragment frag, String title){
        fragmentList.add(frag);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

## CostFragment

```
public class CostFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "CostFragment";
public static ArrayList<Double> drinksPrice = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> drinksName = new ArrayList<>();
private PieChart piechart;
public static ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
private BarChart barchart;
private ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<BarEntry> barEntries = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracking_layout_fragment, container, false);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: " + drinksPrice.toString());

    getPieData();
    getBarData();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    piechart = view.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
    barchart = view.findViewById(R.id.barChart);
    piechart.setRotationEnabled(true);

    getParseInfo();

    addBarData();
    addPieData();

}
```

## getParseInfo() and addPieData()

```
  private void getParseInfo() {

    drinksName.clear();
    drinksSize.clear();
    dates.clear();

    ParseQuery parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Drink.class);
    parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                    drinksSize.add(object.getInt("size"));
                    drinksName.add(object.getString("itemName"));
                    dates.add(getDate(object.getCreatedAt()));
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG, "exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}


 private void addPieData() {

    PieDataSet pieDataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "Each item volume (ml)");
    pieDataSet.setSliceSpace(1);
    pieDataSet.setValueTextSize(14);
    pieDataSet.setColors(getColours());
    PieData data = new PieData((pieDataSet));
    piechart.setData(data);
    piechart.animateY(1000);
    piechart.setExtraRightOffset(10f);
    Legend legend = piechart.getLegend();
    legend.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    legend.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    legend.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
    piechart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    piechart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
    piechart.invalidate();

}

   private void getPieData(){

    for(int i = 0;i<drinksName.size();i++){
        pieEntries.add(new     PieEntry(drinksSize.get(i).floatValue(),drinksName.get(i)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Share this three methods, 
    getParseInfo();
    addBarData();
    addPieData();

Comment: I've added the methods @AkashPatel hope this isn't too much information. I left out the addBarData() as the methods are essentially the same as pieData. Appreciate any help again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move following lines from onViewCreated() to onCreateView():

```
piechart = view.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
barchart = view.findViewById(R.id.barChart);
piechart.setRotationEnabled(true);

getParseInfo();
```

After that in your getParseInfo() after for loop add following lines as:

```
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) 
         {
            for (ParseObject object : objects) {
                drinksSize.add(object.getInt("size"));
                drinksName.add(object.getString("itemName"));
                dates.add(getDate(object.getCreatedAt()));
            }
         getPieData();
         getBarData();
        }else{
            Log.i(TAG, "exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

This is happening because when you call getParseInfo() that will go to background and before you get result getPieData() is called. So to avoid this apply suggested changes.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help regarding this. I hope this will resolve your issue. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I have edited my answer try that. Moreover also share code of method getPieData()

Comment: That has worked now after a bit of shuffling about. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated!